# Does the Windows Runtime Windows.Web.Http namespace provide a way to extract query parameters from a URI?

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime, query-string

I've found that it can be done with the [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but namespace `System.Web` that contains it is not available for WinRT, according to the documentation it's recommend to use the classes from [`Windows.Web.Http`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.aspx) to perform HTTP tasks on Windows Runtime projects, there is anything within this namespace that allows to extract query parameters from a URI as a collection? I tried to look for something within it, but I couldn't find anything that could be used for that.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit:

Note that `System.Web` namespace is not available on WinRT.

Comment: What about `System.Uri` ?

Comment: @L.B I wanted it in a collection like when you use: `string queryString = new System.Uri(uri).Query;
var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);` But using the resources available on `Windows.Web.Http` that is the new way to manage HTTP related stuff on WinRT.

Comment: Zignd, `new Uri("...").ParseQueryString`

Comment: This property doesn't even exists! Proof, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    Uri baseUri = new Uri ("http://www.contoso.com/");
    Uri myUri = new Uri (baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");

    Console.WriteLine (myUri.Query);
```

returns `?date=today`

http://ideone.com/HosL2P